# Trying to iterate through files in a data lake and load them into a table in SQL Server

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I'm using Azure Data Bricks and trying to think of a way to write PySpark code to iterate through patterns of letters and numbers.  I have a bunch of files that look like this:

```
starts like this...
ABS0630.N.006134.gz
ABS0630.N.006135.gz

etc., etc., etc

ends like this...
ABS0630.J.000157.gz
ABS0630.J.000158.gz
```

The 'ABS' stays the same the the '0630' is June 30th.  Is there some brute force way to create a loop that iterates through patterns of letters and numbers and if a pattern matches the name of a file in our data lake, the file gets loaded into a table in SQL Server?  The table and related schema are all setup on the SQL Server side.  If I use ADF to load these one at a time, everything works fine.  I just can't figure out how to iterate through the files, and there are hundreds of files per day, sometimes over a thousand files per day.  The wildcard characters, like '*' and '?' don't work for some weird reason.  All I get is weird errors when I try to use the wildcard characters.

I am trying to used ADF to copy all these files into my SQL Server DB.

Comment: How first 'ABS0630' field gets changing every day. will it be like ABS0701 for next day?

Comment: your third filed seems to be changing sequentially but how second one is getting change. I mean in which order or it remain static as 'N' or 'J'.

Comment: I got it working by taking the 'skip line count' down to a minimum. The issue was that some files had headers only, but no data.  Apparently, when ADF tries to parse a file with no data, but it does have headers, it throws weird errors. I actually had to load header names into my tables, and then delete rows with headers. Maybe it sounds weird, but that's the only ting that worked.

Comment: and where are these bunch of files lying on hdfs? is it some specific directory or it just scattered in different directories or sub directories.

Comment: Right.  Many different directories and sub-directories in a massive data lake.  It's super-easy to copy over tons of data to a No-SQL environment, but when you have to get all that unstructured data into a structured form, it's a real pain.

Comment: how you are loading file to sql server once the pattern get matched with file patterns?

Comment: It's working now.  There was an issue with blank files sitting in the Lake.  Apparently, ADF doesn't deal well with blank files.  I changed a few settings to skips these blank files and it's working fie now.  Thanks for trying to help!!

Comment: never mind. If you can post your findings with a detailed explanation as an answer. It could be used as reference by other peoples also. Thanks